# How to make Android Studio do gradle sync when changing branches automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an issue with Android Studio where it doesn't automatically do a gradle sync when changing branches.

Which causes many false positives problems in code like unresolved references etc...

I have found a workaround to force the sync by running File > Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Is there anyway to force the IDE to do this automatically by scripting or using a plugin or anything.